# Knowledge graph: how to get into it?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, knowledge-discovery

I am looking for internships in the *AI for drug discovery* field and I came upon a new topic, as they describe in the website of a company: *automatic reasoning in a knowledge graph*.

I tried to look for textbooks or even tutorials in the field of knowledge graphs but I genuinely did not find much. Could somebody suggest me any good (introductory) reference on the topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/brylevkirill/notes/blob/master/Knowledge%20Representation%20and%20Reasoning.md) set of notes provides a good overview of (some) of the work in the field of knowledge graphs and automated reasoning, including:

- A [history](https://github.com/brylevkirill/notes/blob/master/Knowledge%20Representation%20and%20Reasoning.md#ontology) of ontology experiments on the web, i.e. attempts to extract structured relationships between online resources
- A [basic overview](https://kgtutorial.github.io)/tutorial of what knowledge graphs are and how to build them from text data
- [Slides](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/%7Egabr/publications/papers/SIGIR-2016-KG-tutorial.pdf) from Google researchers about their methodology for extracting semantic relationships on a web scale (e.g. when you google a symptom, it will show you related disease information)
- [Some interesting papers](https://github.com/brylevkirill/notes/blob/master/Knowledge%20Representation%20and%20Reasoning.md#interesting-papers---information-extraction-and-integration) on knowledge graphs and information extraction
- More related fields and work, see the table of contents for the full list.

Hope that helps!